# Как осуществить запрос к двум таблицам одновременно? mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Смысл в том, что необходимо отобразить информацию из двух разных таблиц в одном цикле с условием по первой таблице и без условий по второй. Условия выборки из таблиц не зависят друг от друга. Ниже - то, что хотелось бы получить в цикл.

---

Суть:
`$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,text FROM auto
                                   id,title1,text1 FROM bullet
                       WHERE auto.podrubs='$cntr'
                       ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $col,20");`

---

Если с первой частью все более менее теперь понятно, то появился еще один подвопрос: **как после while грамотно поступить?** В моем случае необходимо чередовать полученную инфу из этих двух таблиц, а не отображать ее результаты вместе. Если есть принципиально другие решения, то, пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: ммм, а почему нельзя написать: `WHERE auto.podrubs='$cntr'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильнее это было бы сделать в php: сделать два запроса и бежать по переменно в каждом, например. Но этот ваш mysql_query не умеет работать с двумя открытыми одновременно курсорами. Тогда так, через Альпы:

```
SELECT id, title, `text` FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, title, `text`, @arn:=@arn+2 AS rn
      FROM auto
        JOIN (SELECT @arn := -1) ra
      WHERE 
        auto.podrubs='$cntr'    
      ORDER BY id DESC) a
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, title1, text1, @brn:=@brn+2
      FROM bullet
        JOIN (SELECT @brn := 0) rb
      ORDER BY id DESC) b
) s
ORDER BY rn
LIMIT $col,20
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbfcf/19)